# DRF unexpected behaviour in API PUT method when passing value to object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model and I am trying to build an API with PUT method to update the values.

However, when I send request with postman, all of the values are returned wrapped inside   `( ,)`.
For example, if I pass the JSON data

```
{
    "name" = "MyName"
}
```

and then in the API under PUT method

```
data = request.data
animal.name = data['name']
```

the returned values for `animal.name` is `( MyName,)`  (it gets stored in the database like that) which is not what I passed/expect (I was expecting `MyName`).

I used `print (data['name'], animal.name)` to confirm the JSON data are received correctly, and that is so (the print output is `MyName, ( MyName,)` . So the problem is within the API.
I have the feeling this might be related to the `sex = model.ChaerField(choices=...)` as it is the first time I use this method.

I would really appreciate some help in understanding why this is happening and how to solve it.

Below is my definition of model serializer and view.

models.py

```
MALE = 'M'
FEMALE = 'F'
SEX_CHOICES = [
    (MALE, 'Male'),
    (FEMALE, 'Female')
]
class Animal(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='animal')
    farm = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='animal')
    custom_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=8, default= null, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Date of birth')
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices= SEX_CHOICES, default=MALE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s , %s' % (self.user, self.uuid)
```

serializer.py

```
class AnimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sex = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
   
    class Meta:
        model=Animal
        fields = '__all__'
        
    
    def get_sex(self,obj):
        return obj.get_sex_display()
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def updateAnimal(request, pk):
    user = request.user

    animal = Animal.objects.get(id=pk)
    
    data = request.data

    animal.name = data['name'],
    print (data['name'], animal.name)
       
    animal.save()

    serializer = AnimalSerializer(animal, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I would really appreciate some help in understanding why it is happening that my values are returned wrapped around `( ,)` and how to solve it.

Comment: well... you wrote `data['name'],`  the coma creates a tuple

Comment: ... can't believe it ... Thank you